# C code inside vb.net textbox

Tags: c, vb.net

I want to show C code inside textbox so when you click on a button the code will be in a textbox, my problem is VB.net understand that text as a code
i am using this code line for the button

```
    textbox2.Text = "
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
//Set's lcd to the Arduino's ports
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7);
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
"
```

how can i make vb.net ignore C code between "  "

Comment: Why not try using a RichTextBox if you want wrapped text?  Does it have to be a TextBox?

Comment: the same thing happened with RichTextBox i want VB.net ignore that code between " "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to do something like this.

```
        RichTextBox1.Text = "#include <LiquidCrystal.h>" & vbCrLf & _
        "//Set's lcd to the Arduino's ports" & vbCrLf & _
        "LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7);" & vbCrLf & _
        "void setup() {" & vbCrLf & _
        "  lcd.begin(16, 2);" & vbCrLf & _
        "Serial.begin(9600);" & vbCrLf & _
        "}" & vbCrLf & _
        "void loop() {"
```

`vbCrLf` is a Carriage Return, so it will start the next line.

Comment: ops the command stopped here   "if (content == "`")" & vbCrLf & _  not have a power on this command line!

Comment: What's going on here is the quotes inside the if statement are being taken into account and closing your string. So you have to add in a few more quotes to escape that. Like this  "if (content == ""`"")" & vbCrLf & _ .

Comment: that's work but the C code have more "" on that command line, what if i put my code inside a text file, so when i pressed the button that text file will be showing inside textbox? oh the program crash every time i run it ! now error "unknown behavior"

Comment: You could put your C code in a text file if you want. That's assuming the text file will follow your application. If want to go that route, you can use this `RichTextBox1.Text=My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Test.txt")`  That will open a .txt into a RichTextBox.

Comment: you are amazing :) that's work perfectly Thanks allot Timmy now let me do some research to make the text file inside my exe program thanks again :)

Comment: rb1.Text = My.Resources.cpu found it :) mission accomplished